# Intent.createChooser: How we can check sharing image intent count?

Tags: android, android-sharing

1) How we can check which app was selected by an android sharing intent?And how can we know the image shared successfully or not?
Is there a way to confirm if a Share intent in Android was successful or unsuccessful? (For example, if I share a hangout post, I'd like to know if it was successfully posted or know if it was cancelled.)

i have tried out with `onActivityResult` but when i clicked on share button then next i clicked on `outSideTouchListener` (when am selecting an image and when i clicked on outside same output is coming.)

Logcat:

`E/resultCode: 0
E/requestCode: 100
E/resultOk: -1
E/resultCancel: 0`

Answer (score 2):

> How we can check which app was selected by an android sharing intent?

On Android 5.1 and higher, you can find out the chosen activity by using [the three-parameter version of `createChooser()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender)). Otherwise, you cannot determine this, unless you create your own chooser.

> And how can we know the image shared successfully or not?

You can't. There is no universal definition of "successfully", and what happens with the shared content is up to the user and the app that the user chose, not you.

Answer (score 1):

In case of default Android intent sharing we can not get the acknowledgement whether the item is shared or not, the Intent sharing dialog is managed by Android OS itself and sharing in particular app is managed by that app so it is not in our app's control.

If we are sharing images from our application then we can defiantly get the count of selected images to share.

Comment: Yes am getting the count.Am using adapter class and from that view am sharing an image,after senting an image i need to press backpress,then only onActivityResult output getting.